# GNU MakeFile including another makefile with eval funtion Simple Question

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'am trying to create own build system with makefile and the "eval" function. Anyway why i have incorrect output ( **"ABC"** *is printing two times*). How can I get the expected printout?

```
SRC :=

include unit-tests/makefile
define COLLECT_TEST_PROGRAMS

SRC :=

#in included file i have defined sources...

-include unit-tests/$(1)/Makefile

$(1):
    @/bin/echo
    @echo The Module is $(1)
    @/bin/echo $(SRC)

Compile += $(1)
endef #COLLECT_TEST_PROGRAMS

$(foreach TEST_PROGRAM,$(TEST_PROGRAM),$(eval $(call COLLECT_TEST_PROGRAMS,$(TEST_PROGRAM))) )

all: $(Compile)
    @/bin/echo
    @/bin/echo Compiled Programs: $(Compile)
```

OUTPUT:

```
The Module is SampleFileToUT_UnitTests
ABC

The Module is AnotherSampleFileToUT
ABC

The Module is None
DAB

Compiled Programs: SampleFileToUT_UnitTests AnotherSampleFileToUT None
```

include unit-tests/makefile:

```
TEST_PROGRAM :=
TEST_PROGRAM+= SampleFileToUT_UnitTests
TEST_PROGRAM+= AnotherSampleFileToUT
TEST_PROGRAM+= None
```

include unit-tests/$(1)/Makefile looks like:

```
SRC :=
SRC+= ABC
```

**EXPECTED:**

```
The Module is SampleFileToUT_UnitTests
ABC

The Module is AnotherSampleFileToUT
DAB

The Module is None


Compiled Programs: SampleFileToUT_UnitTests AnotherSampleFileToUT None
```

Comment: Hello, Teodor. Nice to see you on stackoverflow. Could you please explain what you mean by `correct "SRC"`. An example of desired output would help too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I added the expected output to the first post. I really don't know how to better explain what I would get: /
Hope you can understand now, if not I will try to describe it better :)

Comment: What I see at a first look is that in your function you assign to `SRC :=` and a few lines down expect the recipe to reflect this assignment in `@/bin/echo $(SRC)`. This does not work because the recipe lines are evaluated and variable-replaced in the last phase of _make_ , so even if you hardcode your makefile the value in **every** of the recipes will always be the one last assigned to `SRC` (ie. from the last line with `SRC:=` in your file). Replace `eval` with `info` to see what you feed into the _make_ parser as a first debug step.

Comment: I know the trick, but I still don't know how to do it :( If I add $$ to the line: @/bin/echo $$ (SRC), it still don't work. And I don't know why. $$ should work but it doesn't work :(

Comment: I would just like to add that I have a little understanding of how the makefile reads makefiles, but I don't know how to get what I would like.
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html

Answer (score 0):

I think, today i have much better day! :)
Answer:

```
include unit-tests/makefile

PATH = /tmp/

define myfn
SRC:=

include unit-tests/$(1)/Makefile

endef

$(TEST_PROGRAM):
    @/bin/echo $@
    $(eval FILE=myfile)
    $(eval $(call myfn,$@))
    @/bin/echo $(SRC)

mytarget: $(TEST_PROGRAM)
```

I am sorry that I do not use the same variable name, but I hope that after all, it may help someone in the future

Based on:
https://gist.github.com/weshouman/f44f330227972073371e1baa510c0d37